# $K$-isomorphism of Intermediate Subfield $F, F' \in \text{Gal}(L/K)$

Tags: proof-verification, galois-theory

Suppose that $L/K$ is a finite Galois extension with $G = \text{Gal}(L/K)$.  Let $F, F'$ be two subfields of $L$ containing $K$.  The author is claiming that they are $K$-isomorphic $\leftrightarrow \sigma F = F'$ for some $\sigma \in G$.

I am not following his argument that $K \subset F(\varphi(\gamma)) \subset F'$.  I really think that it should be $K(\varphi(\gamma))$ in the middle.  Anyway, I followed the general strategy using $K$-conjugates and came up with the following.  Please kindly review if it makes sense.

We already have $F = K(\gamma)$ and $K(\varphi(\gamma)) \subset F'$.  Since $\varphi$ fixes $K$, $\gamma$ and $\varphi(\gamma))$ are $K$-conjugates in $L$, entailing that:
$$[ \, F : K \, ] = [ \, K(\gamma) : K \, ] = [ \, K(\varphi(\gamma)) : K \, ] \le [ \, F' : K \, ]$$
Since  $F \cong F'$, we conclude that $K(\varphi(\gamma)) = F'$.  Because it is a $K$-conjugate of $\gamma$, there exists a $\sigma \in G$ such that $\sigma(\gamma) = \varphi(\gamma)$.  With agreement on $K$ and at $\gamma$, $\sigma |_F = \varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their argument seems clear, $\phi(\gamma)\in F'$ and since the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\phi(\gamma)$ on $K$ is $[F':K]$, $[K(\phi(\gamma):K]=[F':K]$. Thus $K(\phi(\gamma)$ is subvector space of $F'$ which has the same dimension than $F'$, thus is $F'$.